# "Before 23th June" or "before 23th of June"

Tags: prepositions, dates

What is the correct form to refer to dates?

> "I need it before 23th June"

or

> "I need it before 23th **of** June"

Comment: Both are incorrect. _"I need it before June 23**rd**."_ or _"I need it before **the** 23**rd** of June ."_ The last two letters of the ordinal number "third" (3) are _rd._ We use the last two letters of the spelling of the ordinal number as a suffix to the number. "th" would follow 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are incorrect. "I need it before June 23rd." or "I need it before the 23rd of June ." The last two letters of the ordinal number "third" (3) are rd. We use the last two letters of the spelling of the ordinal number as a suffix to the number. "th" would follow 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, etc.
– P. E. Dant